# cast in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am converting my SQL database to MYSQL and I have problem using cast in mysql, please help me to convert this SQL query to mysql

> Here col1 is type of varchar (storing values(01,02,03,04))

```
select * from table1 order by cast(col1 as numeric)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the data type `SIGNED` instead:

```
select * 
from table1 
order by cast(col1 as SIGNED)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a49a/1)